# jQuery: What's the correct code to trigger events in Internet Explorer?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using jQuery 1.2.7 (I cannot upgrade)

In order to trigger events when a dropdown menu selected value changes, I've been told to use the following code:

```
$('#dropdownWidget').bind($.browser.msie ? 'click' : 'change', function(event) {
        //myEvent
});
```

This is a screenshot of the widget:

[image]

It works perfectly on all browsers, however in IE, the event is triggered everytime the user clicks on the widget (even before the new value is selected).

Since I'm triggering AJAX calls, I cannot tolerate this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so why have you added a check for `msie`?

simply try following:

```
$('#dropdownWidget').bind('change', function(event) {
      alert('test');  //myEvent
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I tend to use the click event for all browsers and with IE get the change event to trigger the click event.

```
$('#dropdownWidget').bind('click', function(event) {
        //myEvent
}).bind('change', function(event) {
    if ($.browser.msie) {
      $(this).click();
    }
});
```

If the `change()` event has indeed been fixed as the others suggest, then of course this is redundant. But you may well be stuck using an older jQuery codebase.

Comment: This should not be marked down for not being up-to-date as it is relevant to older codebases as stated.

Comment: I guess your answer is vague since you do not explain which version of jquery you are talking about when you say 'older' and as such does not really help the OP

Comment: @redsquare Well he will know if using change() alone works via his experience I would imagine.  Off the top of my head I do not know which revision this feature was improved on.

Comment: With his version of jQuery, this is the most correct answer. +1 and I don't understand why it is not the accepted one. :S

Comment: @Alex People who have been using jQuery (or indeed any language) for a long time get in to the habit of coding for faults.  Because they do this, it is easy to miss out on improvements.  Maybe he is using an up-to-date codebase and had been told he needed to code around the bug by a more dyed-in-the-wool jQuery coder who was out of date.